# RXJS .filter and distinctUntilChanged on mouseover

Tags: observable, rxjs

In the RXJS autocomplete example you can filter keyup events but how can I filter mouseenter and mouseleave events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same way. `fromEvent` automatically detects the source type and transparently wraps an observable around it. For instance, both options below will work:

```
var entered = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#mydiv'), 'mouseenter', function(e) {
    return e[0].target;
});

var exited = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.getElementById('mydiv'), 'mouseleave', function(e) {
    return e[0].target;
});

entered.subscribe(function(x) {
   $(x).css('background-color', 'green'); 
});

exited.subscribe(function(x) {
   $(x).css('background-color', 'yellow');
});
```

Comment: what's with the `e[0].target` instead of `e.target`?

Comment: Not sure, it threw me too. I was thinking it returned just the event, but in both cases the selector gets passed an array of event, or rather an array of one event.  Might need to raise an issue for it.